# programatically add a function to a javascript file from another javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add some function/code to java script file from another script. I have the below code in A.js

```
/*some comments.. about 4-5 lines*/
module.exports = {
    aaa: aaa,
    add: add
};

var asd = 'test';

function aaa() {
 console.log('ddddd --- ' + asd);
}

function add(a, b) {
 var sum = a + b;
 console.log(sum);
}
```

From another js file i need to add the below function to A.js and update the module.exports list

```
function diff(c, d) {
   ///some code
}
```

I parsed the contents of A.js and the new function with esprima parser
and then with splice function added the code.
I converted the AST to code with recast and wrote it back to the file But the comments are gone.

How to just insert the code without affecting any other content of the original file?

Comment: Not sure if it's what you desire, but you could create a module that: requires the original; patches the function; and exports the whole thing again. Then in your app you require the patched not the original.

Comment: This will not solve my purpose. I need to touch the original file only.

Comment: If you really want to alter the file, you could just open it, append to the end and add a new line at index 3. If you are sure the file will be always that specific way, there is no need to actually parse the js there...

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Seems like there must be a better way to go about this.

Comment: i need to automate, creating function in a js and updating the exports. I will have the function name etc in  a json file. I have to read that json and create the function